# SEO - Canonical url and multilanguage site

Tags: seo, subdomain, canonical-link

Our website is targeting several languages and countries. We make the choice to use subdomain to manage our URLs. We want to avoid to create duplicate content and canonical issues.The content for www. and en. is identical but we plan to adapt the content for en. (in order to target UK).

For main domain, google is understanding:

```
<link href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en" rel="canonical" data-trid="15">
<link href="https://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" rel="alternate" data-trid="16">
<link href="https://example.com/" hreflang="en" rel="alternate" data-trid="17">
<link href="https://en.example.com/" hreflang="en-gb" rel="alternate" data-trid="18">
<link href="https://fr.example.com/" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate" data-trid="19">
<link href="https://de.example.com/" hreflang="de" rel="alternate" data-trid="20">
```

For english subdomain:

```
 <link href="https://en.example.com/" hreflang="en-gb" rel="canonical">
 <link href="https://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" rel="alternate">
 <link href="https://example.com/" hreflang="en" rel="alternate">
 <link href="https://en.example.com/" hreflang="en-gb" rel="alternate">
 <link href="https://fr.example.com/" hreflang="fr" rel="alternate">
 <link href="https://de.example.com/" hreflang="de" rel="alternate">
```

What is the best practice to avoid any canonical & duplicate content issues?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Common Mistakes
Important: Make sure that your provided hreflang value is actually valid. Take special care in regard to the two most common mistakes:

Missing confirmation links: If page A links to page B, page B must link back to page A. If this is not the case for all pages that use hreflang annotations, those annotations may be ignored or not interpreted correctly.
Incorrect language codes: Make sure that all language codes you use identify the language (in ISO 639-1 format) and optionally the region (in ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 format) of an alternate URL. Specifying the region alone is not valid. Via / Read:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid duplicates is to create a unique content for each version, if you can't add content now you have to block these pages or sub-domains by robots.txt or by adding a canonical link to the original page which is en.example.com in your case.

when you have content for each version, remove all these changes and make google able to index them.